# Small Angle Approximation of $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})/|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|$?

Tags: geometry, taylor-expansion, approximation

Assuming that we have two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ of comparable size, forming an angle $\theta$, where $\theta$ is very small.

Is there a small-angle approximation for the expression $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})/|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|$ that is is separable in terms of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ (i.e. $F(\vec{a}) + G(\vec{b}) + K(\vec{a})L(\vec{b})$ for some functions F, G, K, L)?

I tried Taylor expanding $|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|$ in terms of the angle $\theta$ but with no success.

Comment: Via Taylor expansion you can obtain:
$$\frac{a+b}{|a+b|}\approx\frac{1}{|a|}\cdot\frac{a+b}{1+\frac{|b|}{|a|}}=\frac{a+b}{|a|}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{|b|}{|a|}\right)^n$$
However this sum converges very slowly if $|b|\approx|a|$ so I am not sure how helpful this will be for you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how this is an expansion in terms of $\theta$ around 0.

Comment: Using $|a+b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2+2|a||b|\cos\theta$ and approximating $\cos\theta\approx1$ is how I derived that identity above

Comment: Verify if this approximation is enough for you: $|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|\approx|\vec{a}|+|\vec{b}|-0.5\frac{|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|}{|\vec{a}|+|\vec{b}|}(\theta^2)$, where $\theta$ is in radians.